# Mounting using alternate fstab file

Tags: mount, fstab, bind-mount

I need to use an alternative fstab file for mounting a folder in another folder, like the command

```
mount --bind /folder1 /folder2
```

I tried the command

```
mount --fstab /pathToFile.fstab
```

as stated in the man:

> `-T`, `--fstab path`
>
> Specifies  an  alternative fstab file.  If path is a directory then the files in the directory are sorted by `strverscmp(3)`; files that start with `.` or without an `.fstab` extension are ignored.  The option can be specified more than once.  This option is mostly designed for `initramfs` or `chroot` scripts  where  additional configuration is specified beyond standard system configuration.

I create the file this way:

```
/folder1 /folder2 auto bind 0 0
```

but the command

```
mount --fstab /path
```

does nothing.

I added the line from the alternative file in `/etc/fstab` and with the

```
mount -a
```

the folder is mounted correctly.

Does anybody have experience with the `--fstab` option?

Comment: I guess you should try `mount --fstab /path -a` or `mount --fstab /path /folder1`.

Comment: Is your alternate `fstab` file called `path` and is it located in the root directory? This is what your `mount --fstab /path` command implies.

Comment: @Kusalananda /path was an example, my fstab file is in /ftp/mountFile.fstab, the file exist, but I didn't use the -a option, that solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
mount --fstab /pathToFile.fstab
```

is the same as `mount` with no options when using the standard fstab file, i.e. "list mounted filesystems".

To actually mount all automountable filesystems specified in a custom fstab file similar to using `mount -a` with the standard fstab files, you'll need to use the `--fstab` option **together** with the `-a` option:

```
mount --fstab /pathToFile.fstab -a
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer solve my question!